# Is there an automatic way to reduce the legend according to layer content?

Tags: qgis, style

I have style-file with max. amount of types. Some shp-Files doesn't have alle these values. When I load the sld-File there always drawn the max. count of the values. Is there any automatically way to reduce it to current values??

For instance: the value B111-GT6210 is not in the current shp-File[image]